# Understanding Joins

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to get rows back from a database where an id does not equal to the return of id's from a link table. Can this be done using a join?

```
select *
    from module_items_profile people
        where people.item_id not in (
            select link.people_id
                    from link_page_people link 
                        where link.page_id = $page_id
                        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but use a `LEFT JOIN` with the `IS NULL` predicate:

```
select *
from module_items_profile AS people
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM link_page_people 
  where page_id = $page_id
) AS link ON people.item_id = link.people_id
WHERE link.people_id IS NULL;
```